# Paradigm of (reduplicated) "fhefhaked"?

Tags: verbs, conjugation, perfect-tense, old-latin, reduplicatio

Do we have any reasonable speculations about a possible paradigm of archaic *fhefhaked*? I found an unreduplicated paradigm on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Italic_language), but I cannot judge its validity:

> 1st Sing.     *fēkai
> 2nd Sing.   *fēkistai
> 3rd Sing.   *fēked
> 1st Plur.   *fēkomos
> 2nd Plur.   *fēkistes
> 3rd Plur.   *fēkēri

And I'm also specifically interested in a reduplicated version.